# Cannot read property 'split' of undefined in Nodejs

Tags: node.js

```
module.exports = {
  verifyToken(req, res, next){

    if(!req.headers.authorization){
      return res.status(401).send('Unauthorised request')
    }

    let token = req.headers.authorisation.split(' ')[1];

    if(token === null ){
      return res.status(401).send('Unauthorised request')
    }
    let payload = jwt.verfy(token, 'SECRETKEY')
    if(!payload){
      return res.status(401).send('Unauthorised request')
    }
    req.id = payload.subject
    next()
  }
}
```

i am trying to see if the user is authorized to access the mylist resource on frontend.
does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is just a simple typo since you already check if the `authorization`-header exists. So change `authorisation` to:

```
let token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
```

Comment: Great spot is that!